# VSTO Outlook: Avoid MailItem_PropertyChanged from being fired when updating "To" field

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to update the 'To' field of an Outlook.MailItem but I want to avoid MailItem_PropertyChanged event to be fired so I unsubscribe from the event, update the 'To' field and then subscribe to the event again:

```
this.cryptableMailItem.PropertyChanged -= MailItem_PropertyChanged;
myOutlookMailItem.To = something;
this.cryptableMailItem.PropertyChanged += MailItem_PropertyChanged;
```

But it is not working, each time I update the 'To' field, MailItem_PropertyChanged is fired again and again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The event fires asynchronously when the Windows message pump on the main thread runs. If you know that the next `PropertyChanged` event needs to be ignored, why not set a boolean flag that tells your event handler to do nothig? You can then reset the boolean flag in the event handler to make sure you prcocess it the next time it fires.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution, the problem is that MailItem_PropertyChanged fires 3 times for each email address, so when to reset the boolean flag within the event handler? it would be in the last event fired, but how to know this? I know that first is fired for To, then for CC and finally for BCC. I wonder if this is always the order followed by Outlook or not. I could reset the boolean flag in the last event fired, just in BCC and in all cases do nothing, ignore it, am i right?

Comment: Yes, the event is always fired for all 3 properties, so track only the To property and reset after it fires once for that property. Better yet, don't skip the event and instead compare the new recipients with the ones you cached to determine whether your code needs to do nothing.